# Photoshop Extendscript - File is locked - Cant save

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, toolkit

I can't save my file with javascript.
The error when trying to save the file via my script is:

> Could not save a copy as "..." because the file is locked, you do not have necessary permissions, or another program is using the file. Use the "properties" command in the Windows Explorer to unlock the file.

If I press ok, my script tells me "User abort" .

I already successfully wrote a few .jsx with the extendscript toolkit to automate photoshop but this is the first time reading .psd paths from a csv list and opening them in photoshop.

I think the problem is because "var docRef = app.activeDocument;" is created in my savePng function while still in the loop reading my .csv

Here is a part of my code where I am looping all my photoshop files and trying to save them as .png

I do a few functions here to process my automation.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= lineslength - 2; i++){
    if(typeof lines[i] !== "undefined")
    {
        app.open(new File(lines[i]));
        var docname = app.activeDocument;
        var filenamelong = docname.name
        var filename = filenamelong.substring(4, filenamelong.length - 4);
        clickonlayer()
        createlayer()
        isolate()
        maskinput("image_mask")
        try {
            maskadd("image2_mask")
            maskadd("image3_mask")
            maskadd("image4_mask")
        }
        catch(error){
        }
        setcolor()
        deselect()
        savePng(filename)
        activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
        filenew.writeln(lines[i] + "        EXPORTED")
    } 
}
```

Here is my savePng function:

```
function savePng(psdname) {
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var exppath = "C:/Users/Jeremy/Documents/export";
var filepath = psdname + '.png'
var file = new File(filepath);
var opts = new PNGSaveOptions();
docRef.saveAs(file, opts, true);
}
```

Usually in my photoshop scripts I open a file and create the app.activeDocument variable but this time it needs to be created after the file will be opened via the script.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried to use a different path? The error message pretty much explains the issue and it has nothing to do with variables

Comment: Yes I tried a different path. Nothing different. A workaround for me was to use the legacy function "Save for web".

Comment: This might be your problem `var filename = filenamelong.substring(4, filenamelong.length - 4);` With a filename `123.psd` filename becomes `.`

Comment: good point but I have long naming conventions so that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
var filepath = psdname + '.png'
```

I belive there should be

```
var filepath = exppath + "/" + psdname + '.png'
```